# Invoking Rest Client to call WSO2 ESB Service :unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, wso2, esb

i am trying to invoke an ESB service in wso2 from a rest client while invoking i am facing this exception. 
ESB Service: default Echo Service
Rest Clent :

```
public static void main(String a[]){         
        String url = "https://localhost:9443/services/echo";
        String name = "admin";
        String password = "admin";
        String authString = name + ":" + password;
        String authStringEnc = new BASE64Encoder().encode(authString.getBytes());
        System.out.println("Base64 encoded auth string: " + authStringEnc);
        ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();

          Client client = Client.create(config);

          WebResource webResource = client.resource(UriBuilder.fromUri(url).build());

          MultivaluedMap<String, String> formData = new MultivaluedMapImpl();

          formData.add("in", "786");

          ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/xml").post(ClientResponse.class, formData);

          System.out.println("Response " + response.getEntity(String.class));


       if(response.getStatus() != 200){
            System.err.println("Unable to connect to the server");
        }
        String output = response.getEntity(String.class);
        System.out.println("response: "+output);
}
```

This prints out:

```
Base64 encoded auth string: YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=
```

And then throws:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:151)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:648)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:680)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.post(WebResource.java:568)
    at HelloServiceRestClient.main(HelloServiceRestClient.java:76)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler$1$1.getOutputStream(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:234)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.CommittingOutputStream.commitWrite(CommittingOutputStream.java:117)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.CommittingOutputStream.write(CommittingOutputStream.java:89)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedWriter.flush(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.util.ReaderWriter.writeToAsString(ReaderWriter.java:191)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.AbstractMessageReaderWriterProvider.writeToAsString(AbstractMessageReaderWriterProvider.java:128)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.BaseFormProvider.writeTo(BaseFormProvider.java:109)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormMultivaluedMapProvider.writeTo(FormMultivaluedMapProvider.java:99)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormMultivaluedMapProvider.writeTo(FormMultivaluedMapProvider.java:59)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.RequestWriter.writeRequestEntity(RequestWriter.java:300)
    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler._invoke(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:213)
    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:149)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
    ... 40 more
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: You're accessing https://localhost:9443/services/echo which is an SSL site.  Do you have a truststore.jks set up with the ssl cert this is using?  This is rather likely a duplicate, but you need to describe what you've done to determine which problem it is.  Also note that there is the quick way to work around this (configure SSL to not verify certificates) and the right way (add the certificate or the CA for the certificate)

Comment: firstly thanks Abimaran , i am very new to SSL creation , I was created one certificate by using keytool and added to trust-store. and executed the above Rest client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens since there are no public certificates installed in your client to establish a secure connection (https) with ESB.

You can point to the carbon truststore/keystore which contain the certificates.

The code will look like:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", your_truststore_path_here);

System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "wso2carbon");
```

In ESB, the keystore is located at repository/resources/security  (both the keystore and trust-store are there)

Comment: After pointing to the truststore i was getting the below error: response:                                                                                                    <faultstring>The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found is /services/echo?tryit and the WSA Action = null. If this EPR was previously reachable, please contact the server administrator.</faultstring>

Answer (score 1):

My Problem was solved after adding below piece of code and changed the url. Thanks Rajeev for nice suggestion.

```
String url = "https://localhost:9443/services/echo/echoString";
```

`System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "D:/WSo2/WsO2/ESB/wso2esb-4.8.1/repository/resources/security/client-truststore.jks");  System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "wso2carbon");`